# Range of Square Root of X

Tags: functions

The $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ has a domain of $[0,\infty)$. As of in our textbook it is written that range is also $[0,\infty)$. How? $\sqrt{x}=-\sqrt x\space or \space \sqrt x.$ According to me range should be $(-\infty, \infty)$ then.

for example:

1. f(1) = -1 or 1
2. f(4) = -2 or 2
3. f(9) = -3 or 3
   .
   .
   .
4. $f(\infty)=-\infty \space or \space \infty$

Comment: $\sqrt x$ is by definition the positive square root of $x$

Comment: The function $x \mapsto \sqrt{x}$ for non-negative real $x$ is defined, by convention, to take non-negative values.

Comment: @trisct: $0$ doesn't have a positive square root, but $\sqrt{0} = 0$.

Comment: @RobArthan Nonnegative then.

Comment: $f(1)=1$ and only $1$.  $f(4)=2$ and only two, not negative two.  Also, $\infty$ is not a real number so $f(\infty)$ is invalid.

Comment: @trisct: that fixes it. $\ddot{\smile}$.